# Requiring TOTP before every comand in Linux shell

Tags: linux, security, bash

Is it possible to configure say Bash or any other shell in Linux so that a TOTP code is required for *every* command that is run?

As the use case, let's say that I have a production system that is very locked down, and every command *requires* approval by a manager, and to operationalize that I want to setup a OTP for which only the manager has access to.

Comment: In that case: don’t give access to an interactive shell at all. Create scripts and/or Ansible playbooks that can be tested on a test system and only schedule those to run after passing your  desired approval process.

Comment: Ok, so far I´ve found that it is possible to run a specific command before each typed command line instruction ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123034/execute-command-after-every-command-in-bash ). Now I only need to find how to securely run a TOTP prompt from the command line, and that it exits with a different errorlevel on failure.